# How can I enable a Kubernetes networkpolicy for a url?

Tags: kubernetes, networking, policy

In my kubernetes cluster all network traffic crossing the namespace border is blocked and I have to enable it manually with a network policy.

The official kubernetes documentation describes `networkpolicies` via pod labels or ip ranges, but I need to connect to a specific url.
Of course, I can lookup the ip of this url and enable it, but if the ip changes I will get into trouble.

Is there any recommended way to allow communication with only a specific url?

Comment: Which network plugin are you using for your network policies?

Comment: I think the cluster is set up with calico

Comment: from what I know, calico only allows using dns based policies in the [Enterprise edition](https://docs.projectcalico.org/security/calico-enterprise/egress-access-controls).

Comment: as far as i've read the documentation dns based policies work only on GlobalNetworkPolicy cluster wide and not on namespace level?So I have to talk to the admin anyway.

Comment: Would you know where the URL is hosted? I'd use a label for that. Networkpolicy will not allow you to UR: filter.

Comment: yes we know the exact url, but how can a url have a label?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: Not possible.

---

According to Kubernetes API Reference Docs - [NetworkPolicyPeer v1 networking.k8s.io](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.22/#networkpolicypeer-v1-networking-k8s-io), fields you can specify in `egress.to` are:

- `ipBlock`

  > IPBlock describes a particular CIDR (Ex. "192.168.1.1/24","2001:db9::/64") that is allowed to the pods matched by a NetworkPolicySpec's podSelector.
- `namespaceSelector`

  > Selects Namespaces using cluster-scoped labels. This field follows standard label selector semantics; if present but empty, it selects all namespaces. If PodSelector is also set, then the NetworkPolicyPeer as a whole selects the Pods matching PodSelector in the Namespaces selected by NamespaceSelector. Otherwise it selects all Pods in the Namespaces selected by NamespaceSelector.
- `podSelector`

  > This is a label selector which selects Pods. This field follows standard label selector semantics; if present but empty, it selects all pods. If NamespaceSelector is also set, then the NetworkPolicyPeer as a whole selects the Pods matching PodSelector in the Namespaces selected by NamespaceSelector. Otherwise it selects the Pods matching PodSelector in the policy's own Namespace.

Or, in more blunt terms - `NetworkPolicy` can be applied to specific IP range, specific namespace(s), or specific pod(s). URL are not supported.

---

Since you are already using Calico, you may want to have a look at [Advanced egress access controls](https://docs.projectcalico.org/security/calico-enterprise/egress-access-controls), which gives you exactly what you are looking for.
It is, however, **behind a paywall**, being a part of Calico Enterprise.